# Do you need a degree to freelance?

Tags: portfolio, outsourcing

Do clients ask for proofs of certs and education or your portfolio is enough?

I'm a net developer with a couple of years of experience, I never bothered to do beyond high school because where I live developers are very rare so companies don't hesitate to give you a contract after 3 months of trial. I was wondering this because lately I'm having entire weeks with nothing to do

Answer (score 5):

A degree is only required when laws require it. Such as.... (in the United States) A PhD is mandatory to be a doctor. Passing the Bar is mandatory to be an attorney, etc.

Unless laws require a profession to be licensed or have educational minimums, then no you do not need to have a degree to freelance.

Having a degree will almost *always* put you above job candidates without degrees. Some employers will only consider those with *proven* knowledge. If you can do that without formal education you may be fine. However, formal education at least confirms to employers that you studied the area you are attempting to work in.

Answer (score 1):

I have never been asked for any proofs of certs or anything.

That said, a MCSE-Badge or similar on your website does have some advertising effect. But I never encountered one who wanted to actually see proof or anything.

The question is, how do you get your clients. When you get recommended, have worked for them prior or get recognized in any other way as "the man to got to, for this kind of problems" Degree will not play any role in getting the job.

If you compete, like on a portal and the other freelancers have additional qualification to advertise their services, you are likely to get sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need a degree. You need to know the skills in which you are freelancing so that you can complete the tasks assigned to you effectively and successfully

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the freelancer's skills. If any freelancer applies at such kind of job where Academic skills are required then the degree is important.When your client is happy with your service and you don't have any academic degree it doesn't carry any value at that time.